# NPE Argument Error: Parameter value is null (JSF) only when <h:head> is in page

Tags: jsf, jar

I have a jsf page, main.xhtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">

<ui:composition template="WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">Page Title</ui:define>
...
```

Layout.xml is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"             "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<h:head>
    <title><ui:insert name="title">Default Title</ui:insert></title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="theme" name="main.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body>

<div id="header">
    <ui:insert name="header">
        <ui:include src="header.xhtml"/>
    </ui:insert>
    <ui:insert name="toolbar">
         <ui:include src="toolbar.xhtml" />
    </ui:insert>
</div>


<div id="content">
    <br/>
    <ui:insert name="content">
        TBD
    </ui:insert>
</div>

<div id="footer">
    <ui:insert name="footer">
        <ui:include src="footer.xhtml"/>  
    </ui:insert>
</div>

</h:body>

</html>
```

When I try to load the page, I get the following stack trace:

```
Dec 8, 2011 8:58:50 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/main.xhtml]
java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter value is null
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.writeURIAttribute(HtmlResponseWriter.java:985)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.StylesheetRenderer.encodeEnd(StylesheetRenderer.java:108)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HeadRenderer.encodeHeadResources(HeadRenderer.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HeadRenderer.encodeEnd(HeadRenderer.java:92)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:402)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.lmig.cm.ps.editor.filter.SecuredPageFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.lmig.cm.ps.editor.user.UserFilter.handleDeveloperEnvironment(Unknown Source)
    at com.lmig.cm.ps.editor.user.UserFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at com.lmig.cm.ps.editor.filter.SessionTimeoutFilter.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:291)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:859)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:602)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

If I remove the section from layout.xhtml:

```
<h:head>
    <title><ui:insert name="title">Default Title</ui:insert></title>
    <h:outputStylesheet library="theme" name="main.css" />
</h:head>
```

The page will load (of course with no css or title).  Even if I only have this in the page:

```
<h:head>
</h:head>
```

It will not render, and I receive the same error.

I have been working for quite a while, and can not figure out what I am doing wrong.  My hunch is that it has something to do with the version of the jars I have included, but swapping most of them out, hasn't led to a solution.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Argument Error: Parameter value is null 
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HtmlResponseWriter.writeURIAttribute(HtmlResponseWriter.java:985)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.StylesheetRenderer.encodeEnd(StylesheetRenderer.java:108)
```

Let's look at the `StylesheetRenderer#encodeEnd()` source (I'm using Mojarra 2.1.4; I assume that you're also using it as most if not all `com.sun.faces` line numbers in your stack trace match 100% with the source; in the future however please mention exact version):

```
105    String resourceUrl = "RES_NOT_FOUND";
105    if (resource != null) {
106        resourceUrl = context.getExternalContext().encodeResourceURL(resource.getRequestPath());
107    }
108    writer.writeURIAttribute("href", resourceUrl, "href");
```

So, `resourceUrl` is `null` somehow.

Let's look at `ExternalContext#encodeResourceURL(String)` source:

```
311     public abstract String encodeResourceURL(String url);
```

D'oh, it's abstract. Well, let's look at the default Mojarra implementation, the `com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl`:

```
521     public String encodeResourceURL(String url) {
522         return ((HttpServletResponse) response).encodeURL(url);
523     }
```

Ah, it delegates to [`HttpServletResponse#encodeURL()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html#encodeURL%28java.lang.String%29) which should by default not return `null` at all.

So, your problem can have at least 2 possible causes:

- You have a custom `ExternalContext` implementation which is not doing its job in `encodeResourceURL()` properly.
- You have a custom `HttpServletResponseWrapper` implementation which is not doing its job in `encodeURL()` properly.

Putting a debugger breakpoint on line 106 of `StylesheetRenderer` and debugging from there
should tell you which implementations are actually been used.

That the same exception occurs when you remove the `<h:outputStylesheet>` is likely because RichFaces implicitly inserts those components in there as well for own stylesheets. Based on your XML namespace declarations, you're using RichFaces.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the response BalusC.  I wasn't sure if my post was clear enough, but you seemed to understand it.

Comment: We do not have a custom implementation for ExternalContext or HttpServletResponseWrapper.  I put the break point at line 106 as you suggested, and I see that context.getExternalContext is returning a org.richfaces.context.SkinningExternalContextFactory$ExternalContextWrapperImpl.  The problem seems to be that resource.getRequestPath() is returning null.  From what I could tell by debugging, happening when the ConfigurationServiceImpl class is looking for staticResourceLocation, even though I see that in the itemsMap....

Comment: You're right, the `HttpServletResponse#encodeURL()` (unexpectedly!) doesn't throw NPE when you pass `null` into it. What's the implementation of the `Resource` class?

Comment: Ah well, it's the RichFaces resource. So, this exception goes away when you remove the RichFaces components from the page? Perhaps something's seriously messed up in RF configuration. Do you have all the required RF JARs in `/WEB-INF/lib`? There are 4, along with 3 dependencies.

Comment: This is why I thought it was jar related.  This project was working fine, but we converted it to use Maven.  I have compared the pre-maven project to the current one and haven't seen anything out of place...but I am sure that I am missing something.  I have richfaces-core-impl 4.0.0Final, richfaces-core-api 4.0.0Final, richfaces-components-api 4.0.0Final, and richfaces-components-ui 4.0.0Final.  Maven brought in cssparser 0.9.5, sac 1.3 and guava r08.

Comment: Unless you have other ideas, I think I am going to go back to the original project, and replace the jars from WEB-INF/lib with the ones in the new project one by one....